# How to implement Authorize.net tracking code?

Tags: payment-methods, authorize.net

I need to implement Authorize.net tracking code. In case of Paypal I extended `Mage_Paypal_Model_Config` with my own class and rewrote `getBuildNotationCode()` method. Is there any similar method in Authorisenet module?

Answer (score 2):

I've contact with authorize.net support and they advised to use a variable called `x_solution_id`, so in my class I rewrited `_buildRequest()` method and set a needed field.

```
protected function _buildRequest(Varien_Object $payment)
    {
        $request = parent::_buildRequest($payment);
        $request->setXSolutionId('A10000xx');
        return $request;
    }
```